# Access rights not valid for changing template accessing container registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The container registry if update from local with:
`docker push eu.gcr.io/[project]/some-api:v[newver]`

With my owner credentials (Verified with `gcloud auth list`

The upload of the container is successful, and the registry lists the container image.

The instance template is created with the right image and present in the console via an "upload script".

Among other things, the upload script states scopes:

`--scopes= https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append`

When I edit my instance group, via the GCP Console  https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instanceGroups
Opening the instance group using "edit"
Selecting [pushed container] in the dropdown `Instance template` 
and `save`.

I get this error:

```
Update VM instance group "[Instance group]"
[project]
Operation type [patch] failed with message "One or more service account scopes are invalid: '
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append'
```

My user account is "Owner" of the project

My service account is "Owner" (Yeahh I know, trying things out)

Last successful update was last year (Yes its slow moving).

What am I missing ?

Comment: The scope **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol** is normally assigned to a service account attached to a VM instance. How are you editing the instance group - using the CLI, a web browser, etc? Where are you running the command - a desktop, a compute engine instance, etc?

Comment: Another item is **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly**. That permission is insufficient to manage the service configuration. You should have the scope **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management**. This leads me to believe you are running a command on Compute Engine and the assigned scopes are limited/misconfigured.

Comment: If you are using the Google Cloud Console Web GUI, then the roles that a service account has do not apply. Only the roles assigned to your Google Accounts identity apply. If you have the role **owner** then you would not have a **read.only** role as per the error message. Go to the IAM section and double-check what permissions your user identity has in Google Cloud.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!
I have added a number of "compute" roles to my user to no avail - but I'm not sure that is the right approach.

Comment: Just adding random roles is rarely the right approach. Read the documentation so that you know what permissions are required. Then add the required role to your identity.

Comment: I'm quite aware of that. But the specified rights/roles in the error message is not to be found. I assumed (Wrongly) the Compute roles was related.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was my template creation script (Gotten from Google Cloud console) was stating "scopes".

I removed the scopes, created a new instance template via the script and default rights was set.

Comment: Your question does not mention using a script. What scopes were included in the script? Your answer as written is just a comment and not a solution others can benefit from. I am still trying to understand your statement that you were editing the instance in the Google Cloud GUI and the effect of this script. More details please.

Comment: What does it matter what "scopes" I removed?
The template creation script used had wrongly scopes added.
The question does not mention upload script, as I was not aware the template scopes was related to using the template - learning is always usefull

Comment: The difference is in creating an answer that others can **also** learn from.